# How to get started with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

My requirement is very simple. I've a database in `www.xyz.example.com`. Using web service I pull the detail of a song/songs. I store them in an Arraylist. 
The arraylist contains the url of the song. When user press play button, the url is passed to a `service` and song starts playing. I've successfully implemented android's default `MediaPlayer`. But I noticed that it takes too long to prepare. Then I found that `Exoplayer` is there to replace `MediaPlayer`. Now I notice that `ExoPlayer` is not as simple as Mediaplayer. It has so many classes, implementation etc. etc..

I added the latest player in my project using gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.0'
```

Now what should I do? How to actually intialize the Exoplayer? According to developer guide

```
// 1. Create a default TrackSelector
Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
    new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
TrackSelector trackSelector =
    new DefaultTrackSelector(mainHandler, videoTrackSelectionFactory);
```

I cannot get anything here. What is a BandwidthMeter here? What is TrackSelection here ? What is TrackSelector here ?

Again...

```
// 2. Create a default LoadControl
LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

// 3. Create the player
SimpleExoPlayer player =
    ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector, loadControl);
```

Here these are some another confusions. What is the difference between `Exoplayer` and `SimpleExoPlayer` ?

Moreover, I see that most of the projects using ExoPlayer in Github are about playing video over http. How can I achieve my above stated goal? (Please do not advice me to read the demo app. It is not simple.) Can anyone guide me to create a audio player.

Comment: Download the demo project from this link https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer , PlayerActivity has all the code snippets you need to start with Exoplayer